# Ubuntu bootea en el grub command line (NO DUAL BOOT)

Tags: ubuntu, grub

Tengo instalado Ubuntu en un SSD de 240GB y windows en otro SSD de 120GB. (EFI / GPT)

Primero habia instale Ubuntu y luego Windows, al haber instalado windows ya no pude iniciar mi Ubuntu ya que cuando carga este disco inicia como "GRUB command line" y no puedo hacer mas nada.

Estuve buscando y en la carpeta /boot/ no hay ningun tipo de contenido.

Como puedo hacer para recuperar el arranque de mi sistema operativo ubuntu sin perder nada ?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Prueba con [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)... en mi caso me arregló problemas parecidos en algunos pcs hace tiempo

Comment: Si bro lo he hecho pero lei que boot-repair-disk funciona cuando tienes un grub instalado pero en este caso se ve que no se instalo nada porque la carpeta boot esta vacia

Comment: Creo que lo que yo hacia era arrancar con un ubuntu live y entonces ejecutaba el boot-repair, y el ya se encargaba de poner lo que hiciera falta supongo, apenas lo recuerdo :-)  También vigila la BIOS y mira que partición de arranque tiene, a ver si el problema está por alli pues windows acostumbra a meter la zarpa por alli modificando cosas.

Comment: Recuerdo haber leído que debes instalar Windows primero y luego Linux. https://askubuntu.com/q/1145933

Comment: Si bro, he reinstalado ubuntu pero ahora no me aparece el windows y asi sucesivamente. No se que hacer.

Lo raro es que tengo 2 discos duros para cada uno, osea que funcionan por separado no se porque pasa esto.

Comment: ¿has mirado la bios?  boot-repair tambien toca el sector de arranque del disco que windows acostumbra a sobreescribir sin preguntar cargándose el grub o lo que encuentre y mira de arreglarlo

Comment: Entonces ahora si puedes acceder a Ubuntu? Entonces agrega una entrada a GRUB para iniciar Windows. Por cierto, este sitio está más orientado a la programación. Quizá tengas más suerte en otro de [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites), en [TomsHardware](https://forums.tomshardware.com/) p algún otro.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no trata de programación, tal como se establece en el [help/on-topic].